# EF migrations "using System" error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have web application with several modules. One of them is named "System".
When I created migration in another module, EF adds necessary usings into `namespace` scope.

```
namespace MaxPatient.Modules.Appointments.Migrations
{
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
```

I know that in this case, the compiler considers that's the path `MaxPatient.Modules` for the root, and throw error 
`The type or namespace name 'Data' does not exist in the namespace 'MaxPatient.Modules.System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)`

Same problem appears with EF auto-generated files

```
namespace MaxPatient.Modules.Appointments.Migrations
{
    using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure;
    using System.Resources;

    [GeneratedCode("EntityFramework.Migrations", "6.0.1-21010")]
    public sealed partial class AlterResponseTable : IMigrationMetadata
```

The problem is solved by copy/paste

```
using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;

namespace MaxPatient.Modules.Appointments.Migrations
{
```

but I have too much files and want find more beautiful solution.

I don't know, how said to EF, that it created usings outside namespace scope.

May be anyone faced a similar problem?

Thanks :)

Comment: Please, check that you have reference to `System.Data` assembly

Comment: @oxfn, I know problem, I want pretty solution for it :)

Comment: Hey, do you really have namespace `MaxPatient.Modules.System`? If so, then it is a conflict and you should rename it. I guess there is no simple way to make EF generate "using" block outside of your namespace

Comment: Yeah, I really have MaxPatient.Modules.System namespace.